# python wont print a variable right please help as it allways prints somthin random

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
import sys
import time
guess = 0
number_guess = 0
awn = ""
guesses_taken = 0 
name = ""
def start():
    global number_guess
    print("hello user welcome to the number guesser.")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("please enter youre name. ")
    print("hello",name,"now im thinking of a random number between 0 and 20 try to guess is")
    number_guess = random.randint(1,21)
    number()
def number():
    global guesses_taken
    global guess
    global number_guess
    guess = int(input("please enter a number "))
    while guess > number_guess:
            print("That number is to big try again")
            guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
            number()
    while guess < number_guess:
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
        print("that number is to small try agian")
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
        number()
        if guess == number_guess:
            global name
            global awn
            print("well done",name," the number was",number_guess,"you guessed it in",guesses_taken," goes!!! Would you like to do another number?")
            awn = input("y for yes or n for no ").lower()
        if awn == "y":
                start()
        elif awn == "n":
                sys.exit()

start()
number()
```

it allways just prints guesses_taken as a random number and I don't know why  as
you can see hear

```
hello user welcome to the number guesser.
please enter youre name. lee
hello lee now im thinking of a random number between 0 and 20 try to guess    is
please enter a number 5
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 13
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 16
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 17
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 18
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 20
that number is to small try agian
please enter a number 21
well done the number was 21 you guessed it in 12  goes!!! Would you like     to  do another number?
y for yes or n for no
```

and this time it just prints it as a random number  which also it just is not right I have tried a whole bunch of things to try and change it so please can someone explain to me why it is doing this in simple terms as I am still in school and half the answers on hear make no sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems and bad practices in your code. Check this modified example (from your code) to see if you can understand all instructions (nothing fancy, I promise):

```
    def start():
        print("Hello user, welcome to the Number Guesser")
        time.sleep(1)
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        print("Hello ",name," now I'm thinking of a random number between 0 and 20. Try to guess it!")
        number_guess = random.randint(0,20)
        number(number_guess,0)

    def number(arg,counter):
        guess = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        if guess == arg:
            print("Well done, the number was ",arg," you guessed it in ",counter," goes!!! Would you like to do another number?")
            awn = input("y for yes or n for no ").lower()
            if awn == "y":
                start()
            elif awn == "n":
                sys.exit()
        elif guess < arg:
            print("That number is too small. Try again.")
            number(arg,counter+1)
        elif guess < arg:
            print("That number is too big. Try again.")
            number(arg,counter+1)

    start()
```

Since you keep calling the number function avoid using "while". For a single instance of a question use "if". Also avoid global variables unless you really have to use it. The idea behind the change was that you "start" you code and than go the guessing part. You have three possible results, either right, lower or upper. If right go to "start" or finish (sys.exit() is unnecessary from my point of view), if upper or downer call guessing part again but updating the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing +1 twice here.

```
while guess < number_guess:
    guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1 # first increment
    print("that number is to small try agian")
    # guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1 # Second increment. You may wanna remove this
    number()
    if guess == number_guess:
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1 # do a +1 here
        global awn
        print("well done the number was",number_guess,"you guessed it in",guesses_taken," goes!!! Would you like to do another number?")
        awn = input("y for yes or n for no ").lower()
    if awn == "y":
            start()
    elif awn == "n":
            sys.exit()
```

You may wanna increment `guesses_taken` when `guess == number_guess` as it also amounts for a guess.

Also, you will want to reset `guesses_taken` in `start()`

```
def start():
    global number_guess
    print("hello user welcome to the number guesser.")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("please enter youre name. ")
    print("hello",name,"now im thinking of a random number between 0 and 20 try to guess is")
    number_guess = random.randint(1,21) # this is the part that generates #the random number for the user to guess
    guesses_taken = 0 # reset
    number()
```

EDIT:

After suggested changes your code would look like this:

```
import random
import sys
import time

guess = 0
number_guess = 0
awn = ""
guesses_taken = 0 

def start():

    global number_guess
    print("hello user welcome to the number guesser.")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("please enter youre name. ")

    print("hello",name,"now im thinking of a random number between 0 and 20 try to guess is")

    number_guess = 1#random.randint(1,21) # this is the part that generates #the random number for the user to guess
    guesses_taken = 0
    number()

def number():
    global guesses_taken # this is the variable that counts the number of times you guessed
    global guess
    global number_guess

    guess = int(input("please enter a number "))

    while guess > number_guess:
        print("That number is to big try again")
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1 # hear it is again
        number()

    while guess < number_guess:
        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
        print("that number is to small try agian")
        number()

    if guess == number_guess:

        guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1
        global awn

        print("well done the number was",number_guess,"you guessed it in",guesses_taken," goes!!! Would you like to do another number?")
        awn = input("y for yes or n for no ").lower()

        if awn == "y":
            start()
        elif awn == "n":
            sys.exit()

start()
```

But, as @armatita suggested, you can either use recursion (calling `number()`) or iteration (`while`). Not necessary to use both.

Comment: as  you can see I edited the code as you said but now it is still not doing it

Comment: please enter a number 4
    That number is to big try again
    please enter a number 1
    well done   the number was 1 you guessed it in 8  goes!!! Would you like to do another number?
    y for yes or n for no